# Redirecting to different slug with same username

Tags: php, wordpress

Right now users on my Wordpress site have a profile link in this format: `example.com/hosts/username`

What I need to do is when clicked on `example.com/hosts/username` to redirect to `example.com/users/username.`

So basically to switch "hosts" with "users" - the username for each user stays the same.

How can I achieve this? (Plugin would also work)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use .htaccess

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
  RewriteEngine on
  RewriteRule ^/?hosts/(.*)$ /users/$1 [R,L]
</IfModule>
```

Comment: Works great! :) Thanks!